# Clearing Anychart (Javascript) Container before drawing new charts

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web, anychart

I am using anychart JavaScript library to create a pie-chart of my data which is being fetched whenever use changes a dropdown element. Following is the code I am using for this purpose:

```
    var stage = anychart.graphics.create("div_line_pie_chart", 800, 600);
    var chart = anychart.pie(pieData3);
    chart.bounds(0, 0, 245, 300);
    
    chart.title("Line Production Data Overview");
    chart.container(stage);
                
    chart.draw();
```

The problem with this is that it creates a new pie-chart at a new location (some rows under the previous one) every time this
code is being executed and I am unable to find a way to clear the stage first before drawing a new chart at the same location where the previous chart was drawn.

Comment: Can you describe in detail what exactly you want to achieve? Do you need to render an empty chart first and then async fetch data apply it to the chart?

Answer (score 1):

Technically if you set pieData3 to be empty then call:

```
chart.data(newpieData3);
```

it will empty graph